# How to get current method call trace? including Filepaths and Code Line Numbers

Tags: c#, debugging, stack-trace

If Im using this code:

```
static void Main()
{
    A();
}
static void A()
{
    B();
}
static void B()
{
    C();
}
static void C()
{
    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace t = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

I can get this:

```
at test.MyClass.C()
at test.MyClass.B()
at test.MyClass.A()
at test.MyClass.Main()
```

But what can I do if I want more info like this:
   at

```
test.MyClass.C()  at Program.cs line 26
at test.MyClass.B()  at Program.cs line 22
at test.MyClass.A()  at Program.cs line 18
at test.MyClass.Main()  at Program.cs line 12
```

It looks like my post is mostly code; so I need to type more words here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few special (and not well known) Caller Info Attribute Parameters you can use, as an example I have a wrapper around my Log4Net implementation to get Source Line Numbers:

```
//I enhance the Log4Net logging by capturing the caller's name and the line of code number
public static void Error(Type source, object message, Exception e = null, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
 [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    ILog logger = getLogger(source);
    if (!logger.IsErrorEnabled) return;

    if (e == null)
        logger.Error(string.Format("MemberName: {0}, SourceLineNumber of {1}, Message: {2}", memberName, sourceLineNumber, message));
    else
        logger.Error(string.Format("MemberName: {0}, SourceLineNumber of {1}, Message: {2}", memberName, sourceLineNumber, message), e);

}
```

These attributes on optional Parameters allow us to get the member name, file path and source line number:

```
[CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",  
[CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",  
[CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0
```

Log file output:

> ERROR XYZ.Tools.Emailing.Email - MemberName: SendEmail,
>   SourceLineNumber of 129, Message: Sending email failed via Exchange
>   server.

Comment: Is `ILog` important in this method? Because I can find its namespace in MSDN

Comment: ILog is a namespace of Log4Net not system define.

Comment: I gave you an example.You need to call `TraceMessage` in @Hameed answer to call it, typically you log this info in the catch of a try/catch

Comment: @DaveG it's just a NuGet reference, VS -> Tools menu -> NuGet package manager

Answer (score 2):

Yes.You can by using Caller Info attributes, you can obtain information about the caller to a method and all the related debugging information msdn link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information.

```
public void TraceMessage(string message,  
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",  
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",  
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)  
{  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);  
}
```

Otherwise if you can use external libraries to track and log each info ,you can use http://logging.apache.org/log4net/,the documentation is also good enough.

Comment: But how do I use this exactly? I try this but the Trace.WriteLine result is nothing, so back to the basic question, what are the input parameters(2 strings, 1 int) should I feed?

Comment: Since its a console application ,you can replace System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine with Console.WriteLine to see message on the screen.

Comment: I put `TraceMessage("Something happened.");` in `C()` , and both Console.WriteLine and Trace.WriteLine are the same, is this supposed to show what I want in my post description?